# Creating a clicking bot from sound data

Tags: python, librosa

So my goal was to create a bot that would click when it registered that a frequency from a sound file is higher than a certain decibel level. I tried to find anything that would remotely relate to the topic, but didnt get far. Furthest I got was importing librosa and it spewing out errors that I had no clue how to fix
From this code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
audio_file = ('C:/Users/amber/Desktop/test/actualtest1.mp3')
y, sr = librosa.load(audio_file)
```

This error came up.

```
   C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/amber/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/test.py 
C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py:88: UserWarning: PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.
  return f(*args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 164, in load
    y, sr_native = __soundfile_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 195, in __soundfile_load
    context = sf.SoundFile(path)
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 629, in __init__
    self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 1183, in _open
    _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 1357, in _error_check
    raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening 'C:/Users/amber/Desktop/test/actualtest1.mp3': File contains data in an unknown format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    y, sr = librosa.load(audio_file)
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py", line 88, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 170, in load
    y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 226, in __audioread_load
    reader = audioread.audio_open(path)
  File "C:\Users\amber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py", line 132, in audio_open
    raise NoBackendError()
audioread.exceptions.NoBackendError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would like to ask how to fix this or maybe a different way to reach this goal. I'm a complete beginner in programming.

Comment: I glanced over your error message and my suspicion is that your first problem may lie in trying to load from an mp3 file.  A quick workaround could be to convert the .mp3 file to a .wav file (either with a command line tool or in a sound application (Audacity?)) and then try importing that. If you give that a go and succeed, then I will have a look at the second part of your problem.  If you don't succeed, I can provide a way to do that conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to organize this answer as a series of sections of code that when run one after the other result in what I think you want.

To jump over your sound import problem, we'll use one of the sound examples built into librosa. I also include in this section all the module imports we will need.

```
import librosa
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np

sound, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('robin'), sr=None)
```

Then we'll define some constants.  The first two constants allow you to dial in which frequency and what threshold you want to use.  The third is how many samples of the sound time series we'll use for each frequency spectrum calculation we do when we generate the spectrogram from the sound time series.

```
FREQ_OF_INTEREST_IDX = 605
THRESHOLD = -7 # in dB relative to sound maximum
NFFT = 2048
```

The frequency is specified by its index in the frequencies generated when computing the spectrogram, which is slightly roundabout.  If you wanted to specify the frequency in hertz you'd have to do a little more work (since the frequencies tied to each row of the spectrogram are a function of what NFFT you use, are not whole numbers, and the exact frequency of interest might not be in there).

The threshold is in dB but because the reference for the decibels in this code is the max of the signal itself, what this amounts to is highly dependent on the sound being analyzed.

At this point we perform the steps to get a spectrogram from the sound time series.  This amounts to performing a short-time Fourier transform and then converting the output magnitude array to a decibels array using the maximum value of the spectrogram array as the reference value.

```
D = librosa.stft(sound, n_fft=NFFT)
S_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(D), ref=np.max)
```

For our own clarity, we'll compute the frequencies associated with the rows of the spectrogram and see which one is associated with the index we are using.  You could run this step before-hand and inspect the frequencies to find which one is closest to the frequency you care about and thereby choose the frequency index you actually want to use.

```
freqs = librosa.fft_frequencies(sr=sr, n_fft=NFFT)
print(f'Frequency checked is {freqs[FREQ_OF_INTEREST_IDX]} Hz')
```

And then we use `np.where` to find all the frames in the spectrogram row that corresponds to the frequency we are interested in that exceed our pre-determined threshold. Then use `librosa.clicks` to create a click track of equal length to our original sound, with clicks placed at those locations in time. And then mix the click track onto the sound track by weighting them each at 50% and summing them into a combined time series.  Finally, we use `sounddevice` to play the resulting sound to see if it all worked.

```
frames = np.where(S_db[FREQ_OF_INTEREST_IDX] > THRESHOLD)
clicks = librosa.clicks(frames=frames, sr=sr, length=len(sound))
sound = 0.5 * sound + 0.5 * clicks

sd.play(sound, samplerate=sr)
```